# copy text/image to clipboard with jQuery

Tags: jquery, canvas

I've seen some older questions similar to mine but am curious if there are newer solutions available.

**The premise of what I'm trying to do** is provide a user with a sample solicitation email. It includes some text and we'd like to have an image in there as well.

Currently, my code is setup like this...

https://jsfiddle.net/nawfk4ue/

**HTML**

```
<div id="code-to-png" class="container">
    <div class="row-full">
        <!-- Row 1 -->
        <div class="col-md-6 fundraising-stats">
            <h4>Fundraising Stats</h4>
            <p>I have raised 66%</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 fundraising-stats">
            <h4>My Goal:</h4>
            <p>$6,000</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 fundraising-stats">
            <h4>Amount Raised:</h4>
            <p>$4,000</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sampleEmailText1">
    <p>Everyone! I&#8217;m so close to reaching my ! I&#8217;ve raised $XX of my $XX target &#8212; </p>
    <p>will you help me hit my goal? </p>
    <P>Donation link in my bio.</p>
    <a href="#" class="link-canvas">
        <div class="canvas"></div>
    </a>
    <p>test after canvas to see if copied</p>
    <input type="button" value="Copy to clipboard" class="btn primary-btn copyBtn1"/> 
</div>
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {       

/* Function runs to generate the image, its hidden by default */
html2canvas($("#code-to-png"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        theCanvas = canvas;
        document.body.appendChild(canvas); 
    } 
 });

  $('[class*=copyBtn]').click(function () {
    $("canvas").appendTo(".canvas");
    let classNum = this.className.replace(/\D/g, '');
    let classSelector = ".sampleEmailText" + classNum;
    const str = document.querySelector(classSelector);
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(str);
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand('copy');       

  });          
});
```

Now the text all copies just fine **but the canvas and the anchor link that surrounds it do not**.

Any insights into whether or not it's possible to achieve?

I was wondering if it's possible to assign the output of a canvas to an img src somehow maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this one myself.

By taking the starting point that I outlined in my original question, I then was able to convert the canvas into an `img` and using jQuery assign that `img` into the section of HTML content I was planning on copying.

Now, upon clicking copy the text AND the image are all gathered up and ready to be pasted. As an added bonus I've got the image set to open a download prompt should the user like to use it elsewhere.

**HTML**

```
<div class="sampleEmailText1">
    <p>Everyone! I&#8217;m so close to reaching my ! I&#8217;ve raised $XX of my $XX target &#8212; </p>
    <p>will you help me hit my goal? </p>
    <P>Donation link in my bio.</p>

    <!-- This bit here is where the image will reside -->
    <a href="#" class="link-canvas" download>
        <div class="canvas"></div>
    </a>

    <p>test after canvas to see if copied</p>
    <input type="button" value="Copy to clipboard" class="btn primary-btn copyBtn1"/> 
</div>
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {       

/* Function runs to generate the image, its hidden by default */
html2canvas($("#code-to-png"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        theCanvas = canvas;
        document.body.appendChild(canvas); 
    }           
});

$('[class*=copyBtn]').click(function () {
    /* Creating the canvas, turning it into an image, positioning it in the DOM, readying it for download */

    $("canvas").attr('id', 'stats-img');
    var can = document.getElementById('stats-img'); 
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = can.toDataURL();
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    var imgClass = $("body img:last-of-type").addClass('img-for-email');
    $(".img-for-email").appendTo(".canvas");
    $(".link-canvas").attr('href', img.src);
    $(".link-canvas")[0].click();

    /*The copy script */
    let classNum = this.className.replace(/\D/g, '');
    let classSelector = ".sampleEmailText" + classNum;
    const str = document.querySelector(classSelector);
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(str);
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand('copy');  
});

});
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/r87w01f4/**

In the fiddle the image doesn't come along for the copy due to a http vs. https script conflict with how an external script is loaded by jsfiddle.

Locally it works like a charm in Chrome/Firefox/Edge.